# How did Shalya discourage Karna during the Mahabharata war?

Tags: mahabharata, history, karna

A related question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11807/why-did-shalya-fight-on-the-side-of-the-kauravas?noredirect=1#comment29335_11807) discusses the role of *Shalya* in general during the *Mahabharata*. It is said that *Shalya* tried to discourage *Karna* in the midst of the war. How did he do that? Also, how did *Karna* respond to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The story of Shalya discouraging Karna is discussed [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08036.htm) and [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08037.htm)

Addressing Shalya, Karna said:

> Accepting those words (of Duryodhana), the foremost of chariot-warriors stationed on his chariot, viz., the son of Radha, addressed
>   Shalya, that warrior accomplished in battle, saying, "Urge the steeds,
>   O mighty-armed one, so that I may slay Dhananjaya and Bhimasena and
>   both the twins and king Yudhishthira. O Shalya, let Dhananjaya behold
>   today the might of my arms, when I will be engaged in shooting shafts
>   winged with Kanka feathers in hundreds and thousands. Today, O Shalya,
>   I will shoot shafts with great energy for the destruction of the
>   Pandavas and the victory of Duryodhana.

In reply to this Shalya said:

> O Suta's son, why dost thou think so low of the sons of Pandu, all of whom are endued with great might, all of whom are great bowmen,
>   and all of whom are acquainted with every weapon? They are
>   unretreating, of great good fortune, invincible, and of prowess
>   incapable of being baffled. They are capable of inspiring fear in the
>   heart of Indra himself. When, son of Radha thou wilt hear the twang of
>   Gandiva in battle, resembling the peal of the thunder itself, thou
>   wilt not then utter such speeches. When thou wilt behold Dharma's son
>   and the twins causing a canopy, like that of the clouds in the welkin,
>   with their sharp arrows, and the other invincible kings (of the
>   Pandava army), endued with great lightness of hands and shooting
>   (showers of shafts) and weakening their foes, then thou wilt not utter
>   such words.

Disregarding those words spoken by the ruler of the Madras, Karna addressing him endued with great activity, saying, "Proceed."'

In the next chapter following conversation has been done:

> Reflecting on the mighty feats of Partha, and burning with
>   self-conceit and pride, and blazing with wrath and breathing long and
>   hard, he addressed Shalya and said these words: "When stationed on my
>   chariot and armed with my bow, I would not take fright at Indra himself
>   armed with the thunder and excited with wrath.
>
> Shalya said, "Forbear, forbear, O Karna, from such bragging. Thou art in transports of delight and sayest what thou shouldst never
>   say. Where is Dhananjaya, that foremost of men, and where again, art
>   thou, O lowest of men? Who else, save Arjuna, could take away the
>   younger sister of (Keshava) that foremost of all persons, having
>   forcibly agitated the home of the Yadus that was protected by the
>   younger brother of Indra and that resembled heaven itself that is
>   guarded by the chief of celestials? What man save Arjuna who is endued
>   with prowess that is equal to the prowess of the chief of the
>   celestials, could on the occasion of the dispute caused by the
>   slaughter of an animal, summon Bhava the Lord of Lords, the Creator of
>   the worlds, to battle? For the sake of honouring Agni, Jaya had
>   vanquished asuras and gods and great snakes and men and birds and
>   pishacas and yakshas and rakshasas with his shafts and gave unto that
>   god the food he had desired. Dost thou remember, O Karna, the occasion
>   when, slaughtering those foes in large numbers with his excellent
>   shafts endued with the effulgence of the Sun, Phalguna liberated
>   Dhritarashtra's son himself among the Kurus? Dost thou remember the
>   occasion when, thyself having been the first to fly away, the
>   quarrelsome sons of Dhritarashtra were liberated by the Pandavas after
>   the latter had defeated those rangers of the skies (the gandharvas
>   headed by Citraratha)? On the occasion also of the seizure of
>   (Virata's) kine, the Kauravas, swelling with numbers in respect of
>   both men and animals, and having the preceptor and the preceptor's son
>   and Bhishma amongst them, were vanquished by that foremost of men.
>   Why, O son of Suta, didst thou not vanquish Arjuna then? For thy
>   destruction another excellent battle has now presented itself. If thou
>   dost not fly away from fear of thy enemy, know O Suta's son, that as
>   soon as thou goest to battle thou wilt be slain."

Comment: Karna was too generous to get angry, I suppose :P

Comment: Yes its a very nice way to get angry. We should also follow the same.